# Are witches/wizards the equivalent of a devil in China or which cultural thing am I not getting here

Tags: translation, culture

A Guy in my brawl stars clan said 狗男巫 is a delusional name.
Is there a cultural string plucked with having witches/wizards, another guy said it also wasn't a good name.

Just how bad are is that, and if there is something with wizards, then are there any history that I can read on to understand the culture more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joking or not, there might be a tone mixup in this name - 狗 is often negative, and 男巫 probably positive. Ask him/the other guy if 犬男巫 is batter?

Comment: Good to know that dogs are seen a vicious beasts over there, sorry I wasted your time.

Comment: @NiNisanNijackle Dogs are pets and helpers, they are not vicious. But people just have the opinion to look down on dogs because they always follow their masters.